# Oracle SQL - select query with where condition greater than certain moment defined in a timestamp column

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, sql-timestamp

I have a table where there is a column, report_time, whose type is timestamp. A value of it looks like "25-May-20 05.03.20.12000 PM", now I want to filter out all rows whose report_time is greater than or equal to that moment, a pseudo where clause looks like:

```
where report_time >= to_timestamp("25-May-20 05.03.20.12000 PM", "DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF PM")
```

somehow I failed to get it work, even after googling for quite some time.

Please help.

Comment: Use single-quotes, not double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is ok with this syntax:

```
report_time >= to_timestamp('25-May-20 05.03.20.12000 PM', 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF PM')
```